# Pattern to parse this string to a DateTime

Tags: datetime, jodatime

Hey everyone I am trying to parse out a `DateTime` from a string that looks like `"20110406080000.000[-4:EDT]"` and am running into problems with the `[-4:EDT]`

`DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS[ZZ]").parseDateTime("20110406080000.000[-4:EDT]")` results in the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20110406080000.000[-4:EDT]" is malformed at "-4:EDT]"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:673)
    at .<init>(<console>:8)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$...
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UTC -4 and Eastern Daylight Time i believe are what they stand for.

Comment: how about not sending that part to parseDateTime?

Comment: I thought about doing that but it is something i was trying to avoid because i am getting times with different patterns to parse into dateTimes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either

- strip the suffix off before parsing
- write your own DateTimeParser for the end part, using DateTimeFormatterBuilder to combine your parser with a standard parser for the first part